# Downloading file from local folder using vue

Tags: django, vue.js, download

Few hours ago I noticed that `<a href='path' download></a>` don't work in vue, just before I wanted to finish my project. I've searched for a solution for almost 4h, but I didn't find anything, that's why I'm here.

I would like to simply download files (pdf, doc, docx) from my local folder *docs* on the server with vue.
Here is the folder tree:

```
|--src
    |--app.vue
    |--docs
        |--file.doc
        |--file.pdf
        |--file.docx
```

So there is the Template part:

```
<v-row justify="center">
      <v-col
      v-for="(docs, i) in info"
      :key="i"
      cols="10"
      >
        <v-card>
          <v-row>
            <v-col
            cols="10"
            >
              <v-icon large>mdi-file-document-outline</v-icon> {{ docs.name }}
            </v-col>
            <v-col
            cols="2"
            >
              <v-row><a :href="docs.file" download><v-icon color="green" large>mdi-download</v-icon></a></v-row>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

...and the script section:

```
  import axios from 'axios'
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        info: null,
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      axios
        .get('http://localhost:8080/Project/Orders/')
        .then(response => {this.info = response.data.data})
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
 }
```

I'm using axios to get data from database (id, name, file=path) with Django (backend). I'd like to download files from *docs* folder without Django, but if anyone thinks it would be better idea to use it I'll be greatful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
/ ...
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = '... path to donwload';
link.setAttribute("download", "file.doc");
link.click();
```

You need your docs folder on your public directory.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Is it possible to add another public directory (I mean makes *docs* folder a second public directory or something like that)? I already configure Django to put files into this *docs* folder. Of course I can change it, but maybe creating additional public directory will be faster and easier

Comment: You must have only one directory to save static files. I think is not possible